# How to programatically check a Checkbox in Android?

Tags: android, checkbox

i was searching on the net for this for nearly 2 hours, but couldn't find anything working for me.

simple, I have an android App, with a listview, that includes checkboxes.

Now, when I click a button, all I want is that one checkbox gets checked (and that this is visible on the screen)
No matter what i tried so far, the checkbox just won't get checked.

thats my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();
List<String> checkedMedia = new ArrayList<String>();
ExpandableListView listView;
MyExpandableListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createData();
    listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
            groups);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.expandGroup(0);
}


public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
    boolean checked = checkBox.isChecked();

    View chBoxParent = (View) checkBox.getParent();
    TextView textView = (TextView) chBoxParent.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String medium = textView.getText().toString();

    if (checked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "checked: " + medium, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "unchecked: " + medium, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    View view0 = adapter.getChildView(0, 0, false, null, null);
    CheckBox cb0 = (CheckBox) view0.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    cb0.setChecked(true);
    cb0.setWillNotDraw(false);
    cb0.invalidate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



public void createData() {

        Group group = new Group("Test ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            group.children.add("Sub Item" + i);
        }
        groups.append(0, group);

}
```

}

Comment: you need to set CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener for checkbox and not onClickListener

Comment: whether you want to  set checkbox as checked what are all items  are visible in listview when you click on button

Answer (score 4):

You can check a checkbox programatically like this...

```
cb0.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cb0.setChecked(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: From code his problem seem to be is, OP expecting onCheckboxClicked(View view) should get called if checkbox is checked which is not getting called as OP has to implement OnCheckedChangeListener. From his code checkbox will get checked but onCheckboxClicked will not be called/executed.